# Google Sites API - File Cabinets: Spaces and extension separator (.) are removed from file names

Tags: c#, google-sites

We have a series of internal reports that we update regularly from our internal databases. We built an application in C# that uploads these reports to a Google Site. Everything works fine, except that the name of the file shown to the final user in the File Cabinet does not include the original spaces nor the extension separator (.)

For example, *Stock per warehouse.pdf*  is shown as : *Stockperwarehousepdf*

Below is a simplified version of the code.

```
private AtomEntry UploadAttachment(string filename, AtomEntry parent, string title, string description)
        {
        SiteEntry entry = new SiteEntry();           

        AtomCategory category = new AtomCategory(SitesService.ATTACHMENT_TERM, SitesService.KIND_SCHEME);

        category.Label = "attachment";
        entry.Categories.Add(category);

        AtomLink parentLink = new AtomLink(AtomLink.ATOM_TYPE, SitesService.PARENT_REL);

        parentLink.HRef = parent.SelfUri;

        entry.Links.Add(parentLink);                        
        entry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource(filename, MediaFileSource.GetContentTypeForFileName(filename));
        entry.Content.Type = MediaFileSource.GetContentTypeForFileName(filename);


        entry.Title.Text= title;                
        entry.Summary.Text = description;                        

        AtomEntry newEntry = null;            

        newEntry = service.Insert(new Uri(makeFeedUri("content")), entry);  
}
```

The key line is where the MediaFileSource object is created. Any idea of what we are missing? I've tried all sort of changes :(

Answer (score 0):

```
entry.Title.Text = entry.MediaSource.Name;
```

is missing